# How to write a method with a parameter in Selenium 2?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, pageobjects

Testing this site: http://store.demoqa.com/

My test verify that be can add and remove the product from cart.

I wrote a method without a parameter that looks like this:

```
public AllProductPage chooseProduct() {
        //Click on product iPhone5
        driver.findElement(By.className("wpsc_buy_button")).click();
        //Expected: Product "iPhone5" has been opened
    return new AllProductPage(driver);
    }
```

I need to write a method with a parameter and choose the product in the test and not in the code that I wrote.

```
@Test
    public void verifyThatBeCanAddAndRemoveTheProductFromCart() throws InterruptedException {

        ImplicitWait(driver);

        HomePage onHomePage = new HomePage(driver);
        System.out.println("Step 1");
        AllProductPage onAllProductPage = onHomePage.clickOnAllProduct();
        System.out.println("Step 2");
        onAllProductPage.chooseProduct();
        onAllProductPage.buttonGoToCheckout();
        onAllProductPage.submitForm();
        System.out.println("Step 3");
        Assert.assertTrue(onAllProductPage.getMessage().contains("Oops, there is nothing in your cart."));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm don't know what kind of data you'd like to pass to the function, but you can try to pass a String containing the product name, like the following:

```
public AllProductPage chooseProduct(String productName) {
    //Click on product received in parameter
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'productcol')][descendant::*[contains(text(),'"+productName+"')]]//input[@class='wpsc_buy_button']")).click();
    //Expected: Product has been opened
    return new AllProductPage(driver);
}
```

Your test may look like this:

```
    @Test
    public void verifyThatBeCanAddAndRemoveTheProductFromCart() throws InterruptedException {

        ImplicitWait(driver);

        HomePage onHomePage = new HomePage(driver);
        System.out.println("Step 1");
        AllProductPage onAllProductPage = onHomePage.clickOnAllProduct();
        System.out.println("Step 2");
        onAllProductPage.chooseProduct("iPhone 5");
        onAllProductPage.buttonGoToCheckout();
        onAllProductPage.submitForm();
        System.out.println("Step 3");
        Assert.assertTrue(onAllProductPage.getMessage().contains("Oops, there is nothing in your cart."));
    }
```

Note that in this example the product is fixed in the test code, but it could be a variable as well.

Comment: This is my error now: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(@class,'productcol')][descendant::*[contains(text(),'iPhone5')]]//input[@name='wpsc_ajax_action']"}

Comment: Instead of 'iP‌​hone5' use 'iPhone 5' in the xpath. The text you pass to the funciont needs to match exactly like shown in the page.

Comment: This is error now : org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: I'm so sorry, the xpath was really locating the wrong input. I edit the answer, now the xpath is correct.